# Change EXIF Data for Proper iPhone Recognition

Tags: ios, linux, jpeg, photo

I have many photos on a Linux server -- many of them scanned older photos which have older real dates but newer (incorrect) EXIF dates (because of the scanning).  I want to change the EXIF dates to their real dates (e.g. using exiftool on Linux) and then transfer them to my iPhone.  I can successfully change the EXIF dates as shown in the image below (old photo from 1910):

[image]

...(I couldn't change "File Modification Date/Time", "File Access Date/Time", nor "File Inode Change Date/Time" using exiftool, but I'm working under the assumption that these aren't the primary metadata that any device/software SHOULD be using to ascertain date [e.g. "CreateDate" and "Date/Time Original" which I can change] ).  Anyway, after making these changes and then after transferring them to the iPhone, the iPhone stamps them with the date/time of the transfer to the iPhone, effectively stomping or ignoring all EXIF data (this further validates my assumption that the three EXIF tags I couldn't change [mentioned above] have no significance since the iPhone is reporting a totally new date/time that is equal to the date/time of the transfer to the iPhone).  Argh.  Google Photos does the same thing.  Since most modern software now automatically sorts by date (presumably using the EXIF data) this is fundamentally problematic and such an obvious feature that should be supported that I'm frustrated that this is so difficult.  I've tried other approaches like creating albums on the iPhone with the year name (e.g. album "1910") ... but this is fundamentally flawed because the photos placed in those albums will still have incorrect EXIF date data and any operation to "view by date" will still be incorrect (the album names are just names with no metadata significance).  Are there date limits?  Do I just need the right tool?  I want to process large batches of files, so any tool that doesn't allow batch processing wouldn't be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of experimentation, the key seems to come down to very fine details regarding which specific tool/app is used for photo transfer and how the image is transferred to the iPhone.  My images are stored on a Linux server and I often use FTP Client Pro to transfer/view/edit these files from the iPhone.  FTP Client Pro has a few ways to transfer images from the Linux server to the iPhone: "Download", "Export", and "Save to Photo Album" being relevant here.  "Download" simply downloads from the Linux server to FTP Client Pro's sandboxed storage -- not relevant since I am interested in saving images to my iPhone Photos and ultimately iCloud Photos.  "**Export" followed by "Save Images" actually saves the image files from the Linux server (with dates modified using exiftool as described in the original post) to the Camera Roll -- with the (modified and correct) EXIF date tags -- this can be done in bulk with FTP Client Pro so this is clearly a solution that works well.**  As a side note for completeness, choosing "Save to Photo Album" saves the file from the Linux Server to the Camera Roll but seems to ignore the (modified and correct) EXIF date tags (iPhone tags it with the date of the transfer, seemingly ignoring the DateTimeOriginal or CreateDate tags).  In the end, the approach highlighted in bold within this answer appears to provide a solution where I can change the EXIF dates on all of my photos where needed on the Linux server easily in bulk (esp. for scanned old photos) and then transfer those photos while retaining the (modified and correct) EXIF data.  The other specific tool/app which may have a similar workable solution is Documents by Readdle, which I also use -- but since I solved my problem with FTP Client Pro, I didn't dig into the details of how to achieve the same thing with Readdle Documents.  The point here is that this problem's solution will depend on which tool/app you choose to transfer photos from a PC to an iPhone and how both the tool/app and the iPhone handle EXIF data preservation.